# Походження слова "футболка"

Tags: етимологія

> [ФУТБО́ЛКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/futbolka), и, жін. Спортивна трикотажна сорочка з виложистим
>   коміром.

В [Етимологічному словнику української мови. Том 6.](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/978-966-00-0197-8/978-966-00-0197-8.pdf) (ст. 142) містить слово "футбол", там же слова "футболіст" та "футболка".

[image]

Тобто це і є спільне похлдження для трьох слів? Чи слово "футболка" має іншу етимологію?

Comment: Має бути якесь усталене правило утворювання іменників у значенні "для іменник". Принаймні відразу згадується схожий приклад **бейсболка**

Answer (score 1):

Так, ЕСУМ вказує на спільне походження слів.

Крім того в статті "[Історія футболки](http://coomtshirt.com/uk/istoriya-futbolki/)" (не офіційне джерело, а тому інформація не є 100% достовірною") пише:

> А російська назва «футболка» з’явилося після того, як її в якості
>   спортивної форми стали носити футболісти.

Хоч тут пише, що назва "російська", але гадаю, що в українську мову та російську слово футболка потрапило одночасно (можливо, справді із розвитком футболу).

Тако на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/futbolka) пише, що "футболка" походить від "Football".